# Graphical view of rows in Hive

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive

Suppose I load data from some file into a Hive table. The data gets loaded successfully. Now in order to see the records I run a select query which then runs a Map Reduce at back end and hence shows all the records.

Now my question is can't I see all the records graphically by some user interface, like we have in various RDMS tools like TOAD or MYSQL?

Answer (score 0):

TOAD has a version that supports hive.
Take a look [here](http://www.toadworld.com/products/toad-for-cloud-databases/default.aspx).
You can also use [DBVisualizer](http://www.dbvis.com/) for example

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below applications

**1) Squirrel SQL Client (with hive jdbc driver)**

```
http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/
```

JDBC driver for hiveserver2 (try either links below)

```
http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hive/hive-jdbc/0.8.1/hive-jdbc-0.8.1.jar
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/h/Downloadhivejdbc0100jar.htm
```

**2) Aqua DataStudio**

```
http://www.aquafold.com/aquadatastudio.html
```

**3) HUE (Web UI)**

```
http://gethue.com/
```